# Control javascript module initialization (dropzone)

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am trying to manually instantiate a dropzone. For that, I need first to set:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

The problem is that I do not know where to do that. Either I do it to early, and Dropzone is not yet defined, or I do it too late and Dropzone has already attached to all dropzone elements.

Currently I am trying:

```
<body onload="myOnload()">    
    ...
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function myOnload() {
       Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
       // create here my dropzones programatically
     }
    </script>
</body>
```

But this is just too late: dropzone has already loaded and initialized the components, which have no url (since I am not using forms), and fails.

How to control when Dropzone starts initializing components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in other's question comment I am not an expert on how the pages are loaded, but i am going to try to explain the process, or at least how I think the process works.

The dropzone library doesn't try to attach to the elements until the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired, this is kind of the same that the `onload` attribute for your body tag but not quite, I am not completely sure but I think the `onload` waits for a few more things before trigger.

So what I believe its happening is that first the `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered and Dropzone auto attaches to the `.dropzone` elements. A bit later the `onload` event is fired and your `myOnload()` function is called, what is to late because dropzone is already attached.

To solve this you have to include the script where you set `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false` after the library but with no wrap.

```
<script src="{% static 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bower_components/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 function myOnload() {
   // create here my dropzones programatically
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it outside and then add manually what you need

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 function myOnload() {
   // create here my dropzones programatically
 }
</script>
```

This script tag should be writing before the plugin include:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 function myOnload() {
   // create here my dropzones programatically
 }
</script>
<script src="{% static 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bower_components/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Puttin it outside the `myOnload` gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined`, since well, Dropzone is not yet loaded.

Comment: So I need to load dropzone.js before running my javascript. But as soon as Dropzone is loaded, it attaches to all dropzone elements, which is *exactly* what I want to avoid. How to solve this catch-22?

Comment: I have discovered that putting dropzone.js in the head works, but this is just a hack: dropzone still tries to attach, but since the body is not loaded, there are no elements to attach to.

Comment: That's weird, I don't know what happens. It's obvious that put autoDiscover before the include it doesn't works, but it's my mistake. According with this http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically you haven't got to make anything more.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's what I am trying to follow, but does not work.